# Прописная в термине

Tags: прописная

Почему Западная Украина - это термин, а восточная Украина - не термин?

Неофициальные названия государств и их частей, образные названия географических объектов также пишутся с прописной буквы, например: Советский Союз, Страна Советов, Советская Башкирия, Полтавщина, Зауралье, Белокаменная (Москва).

Восточная Украина - это неофициальное название части государства?

И тогда пишем с прописной?

Comment: @doom, Следует править вопрос, а не добавлять комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не термин, это топоним. Ответ – так сложилось исторически. Западная Украина – это не просто западная часть Украины, а особый регион, включающий определенные территории, ранее принадлежащий Польше и т.д.